# SQL-Server Update - implementing incremental value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I have a table (called `mytable`) that contains two columns: `ID` and `counter`.

I want to implement an incremental counter for updating the `counter` values. Each time, increase by 1.

Basically, it's should run like this:

```
UPDATE mytable
SET [counter] = [counter] + 1
WHERE ID = @theID
```

I made up a small application that running a for-loop from 1 to 10,000 and check if my counter will be equal to 10,000 at the end.

With a single thread application, it's working fine. But, when I'm running few instances of my application, then the `counter` value is smaller than expected.

For example, running the application 3 times and at the end the value of `counter` is 29,980 (expected 30,000).

I understand that this is a concurrency problem. So, I checked and it's seems like SQL `UPDATE` statement is "atomic" command. So, I'm guess that same command cannot happens twice at the same time.

Is this true? So, how I'm loosing some values in my `counter` column?

If not, what else can be the problem?

Comment: Your understanding that the `UPDATE` is atomic is correct.  I think we'll need to see the code too.

Comment: Why not just use IDENTITY to do the increment for you?

Comment: Dane, please explain?

Comment: He asks why your ID column isn't an IDENTITY column?

Comment: Dan, nothing special in my application. I'm have a for-loop that running for 10,000 iterations. Each iteration it's calling a stored procedure that executing the SQL mention in the question.

Comment: Allan, my ID column is Identity column. But, this is not the problem. The problem is increase the value of "counter" by 1.

Comment: An identity column increases with 1 unless you've specified another increment value.
Also - I wouldn't use the value of the ID to verify a count - I'd count number of rows for knowing the number of rows.

Comment: Does your procedure execute any other query in that table? If it does, you could create an trigger to update 'counter'

Comment: Try experimenting with different isolation levels.

Comment: Show your multithreaded application code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm very curious as to why this has happened... but you could try and lock the table if you're worried that the same counter has been read twice.

```
 BEGIN TRANSACTION
     DECLARE @Counter INT; 

     SELECT @Counter = [Counter]
     FROM   mytable WITH ( TABLOCK, HOLDLOCK )

     UPDATE mytable
     SET    Counter = @Counter + 1;

 COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

Answer (score -1):

you can update your code to use @@ROWCOUNT.

Check if it works fine like this:

```
  UPDATE mytable
  SET [counter] = (Select @@ROWCOUNT From mytable where ID=@theID) + 1
  WHERE ID=@theID
```